# CakePHP not completely decrypting virtual field

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption

I'm running into an issue in my CakePHP (2.4.1) app where the virtual field in one of my models is not properly being decrypted using Cake's `Security::rijndael()`. In my User model, the display field is defined as

```
public $virtualFields = array( 'name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)' );
```

Both User.first_name and User.last_name are encrypted, and User.name is the displayField for the model. In the AssignedShift related model (User hasMany AssignedShift), the User.name field is not being properly decrypted. Here is an example return:

```
Array(
    [1] => Test|�d�F�3��������������S0�Dy=>�dJ���sP�4�F�n�؄s-#���7P���n�ʙ.�C�@���˷C�z��(;Eu)�
)
```

This is the only model that this happens on, so I'm pretty confident my afterFind method is working properly. In any case, below are the functions for encrypt/decrypt:

```
/*AppModel.php*/
function _afterFind($results, $primary) {

    if( $primary ) {
        foreach( $results as $key => $val) {
            if( isset( $val[$this->alias] ) ) {
                $results[$key][$this->alias] = $this->doAfterFind( $results[$key][$this->alias] );
            }
        }
    } else {
        if( isset( $results['id']) ) {
            $results = $this->doAfterFind($results);
        } else {
            foreach( $results as $key => $val ) {
                if( isset( $val[$this->alias] ) ) {
                    if( isset( $val[$this->alias]['id'] ) ) {
                        $results[$key][$this->alias] = $this->doAfterFind( $results[$key][$this->alias] );
                    } else {
                        foreach( $results[$key][$this->alias] as $key2 => $val2 ) {
                            $results[$key][$this->alias][$key2] = $this->doAfterFind( $results[$key][$this->alias][$key2] );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

public function doAfterFind($data) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $val) {
        if( !empty( $val ) && strlen( $val ) >= 88) {
            $data[$key] = Security::rijndael( base64_decode( $val ), Configure::read( 'Security.cipherSeed' ), 'decrypt' );
        }
    }
    //My attempt at hacking it back together
    if(array_key_exists('first_name', $data)) {
        $data['name'] = $data['first_name'] ." ". $data['last_name'];
    }
    return $data;
}

/*AssignedShift.php*/
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    return $this->_afterFind($results, $primary);
}
```

Both models were created from the console - User has been modified but I haven't touched the relationships, and AssignedShift is completely untouched. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks correct. might be encode

Comment: try this // public $virtualFields = array( 'name' => 'CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name)');

Comment: @Jason You should show the code in question where the decryption happens, and explain what kind of encryption you are using in case its not obvious. Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: @ndm - Thanks, I've added the code above. I guess just because I assume it's working doesn't mean it actually is!